# how to resolve ~ root link from a TagHelper

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-tag-helpers, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

In ASP.NET 5 MVC6 RC1 - I have a ViewComponent which is designed to represent my traditional "left hand side of the screen" main menu.

I am writing my first TagHelper to represent each menu item link.

I am stuck at the part where I am trying to create a hyperlink.

**How do I resolve `~/dashboard/summary?`**

If I display the menu on this page, the link appears as `/dashboard/~/dashboard/summary`.

`@Url.Content("...")` displays `@Url.Content("...")` i.e. is not processed as razor.  The tag helper outputs pure.

Ideally, I would like the solution to be .NET Core compatible as I am eventually aiming for a .net core deployable solution.

See below:

```
namespace Website
{

    /// <summary>
    /// <MainMenuLink area="" controller="" action=""></MainMenuLink>
    /// 
    /// to render
    /// 
    ///  <a href="~/account/manage/ChangePassword" class="list-group-item @GetClassName("manage", "changepassword")">
    ///    <p class="list-group-item-text"><i class="fa fa-terminal"></i>&nbsp;&nbsp;Change my password</p>
    /// </a>
    /// 
    /// 
    /// </summary>
    [HtmlTargetElement(Attributes = "area, controller, action")]
    public class MainMenuLinkTagHelper : TagHelper
    {
        [HtmlAttributeName("area")]
        public string Area { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("controller")]
        public string Controller { get; set; }

        [HtmlAttributeName("action")]
        public string Action { get; set; }

        public UrlHelper urlHelper { get; set; }

        public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
        {
            output.TagName = "a";    // Works    
            // Stuck here - I want ~/ to resolve to the base root.  
            // At the moment the address is here is localhost:XXXXX/dashboard/~/dashboard/summary

            // Would prefer to use a method which can be used with .net core and not System.Web

            output.Attributes.Add("href", "~/dashboard/summary");
            output.Content.SetHtmlContent("Click me");

        }        
        /// <summary>            
    }
}
```

Thanks!
Dan.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Add a constructor dependency for `IUrlHelper` in your tag helper. Then use the same [extension methods](https://github.com/aspnet/Mvc/blob/master/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc.Core/UrlHelperExtensions.cs) you can use in a view to generate the urls like `IUrlHelper.Action(actionName, controllerName)`:

```
private IUrlHelper urlHelper;
...
public MainMenuLinkTagHelper (IUrlHelper urlHelper)
{
    this.urlHelper = urlHelper;
}
...
public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output)
{
    output.TagName = "a";
    output.Attributes.Add("href", this.urlHelper.Action(this.Action, this.Controller));
    output.Content.SetHtmlContent("Click me");
}
```

**Edit: ASP Core version 1.0**

It is no longer possible to inject directly an `IUrlHelper`.
You need to inject both `IActionContextAccessor` and `IUrlHelperFactory`, then get an `IUrlHelper` with them.
For example:

```
private IUrlHelper UrlHelper => 
    this.urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(this.actionAccessor.ActionContext);
```

Comment: Wicked awesome - used string url = _urlHelper.Action(Action, Controller, new { area=Area });

Answer (score 13):

**ASP Core 2.0** does not appear to include `IActionContextAccessor` in the `IServiceCollection` by default so you will need to register it at startup for the accepted solution to work:

```
services.AddSingleton<IActionContextAccessor, ActionContextAccessor>();
```

Otherwise there is an attribute provided that can set a property of the `TagHelper` to the `ViewContext` which extends the `ActionContext`

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Rendering;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Routing;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ViewFeatures;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Razor.TagHelpers;

[HtmlTargetElement("my-tag")]
public class MyTagHelper : TagHelper {

    private readonly IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory;

    [ViewContext]
    [HtmlAttributeNotBound]
    public ViewContext ViewContext { get; set; }

    public MyTagHelper (IUrlHelperFactory urlHelperFactory) {
        this.urlHelperFactory = urlHelperFactory;
    }

    public override void Process(TagHelperContext context, TagHelperOutput output) {
        var urlHelper = urlHelperFactory.GetUrlHelper(ViewContext);
    }
}
```

note: The `ViewContext` property must have a public set method

Comment: Why ASP.Net Core 2 makes this harder to achieve? I think that access to `UrlHelper` should be much easier